# Change domain without 404 error code?

Tags: url, seo, http-status-code-404

I have changed all the URLs of my website. (Domain is the same. For example: http://www.example.com/category/sample ----> http://www.example.com/Category/Sample)
Now it seems to have lots of 404 pages that are effecting my SEO.
What should I do to solve this problem? Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: i'm little bit confused about your need why you start the seo though your domain is not fix i mean need to change?

Comment: I don't want to change the domain. I want to change the rest of it. As u can see in the question I want to change small letter of the words to capital letters

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with changing the Context root for your website. Context roots determine the URL of any web-application.

Click [here](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-change-web-project-context-root/) for a short  article for making changes to context-roots.

The process may change based on the Server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Just create sitemap.xml file. There are many online sites available that will create free sitemap.xml file. Just you have to submit your website url and within few seconds they will generate sitemap.xml file.  Download this sitemap.xml file and place it into your root directory. When crawler run through your website it will automatically update your all links and within few days you will see all updated links are present in search resulting page like google search engine.

Note: Also, dont forget to update sitemap.xml file path in robot.txt file.